# Can I load JPA mappings from Java annotations and save them back as XML?

Tags: java, xml, jpa, orm, annotations

Is it possible to define JPA mappings with annotations only, and then programmatically save this mapping data back to some orm.xml file?

There is discussion in the team as to whether to use annotations or XML, and I want to check whether, if we start with annotations, we can simply switch at a later point without rewriting all the XML files by hand.

Comment: would you like to keep annotation information in xml file?

Comment: Yes, I would like to generate the orm.xml file that is equivalent to the annotations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Eclipse Dali project has a feature request ([bug 138622](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=138622)), but it is not in our plans to support this. In the Juno release we did add support to convert the global metadata (named queries, generators) from annotations to xml ([bug 353149](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=353149)). As far as I know there is not a tool for converting all of the JPA annotations metadata into an orm.xml file.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if there is a tool.

At runtime, if you are using EclipseLink you can use the XMLEntityMappingsWriter to write JPA metadata to XML.  It is internal API, but it does work.

Comment: Cool, thanks — but how do I get an instance of my `XMLEntityMappings` then?

Comment: For now, I’m accepting the other answer but would revise it if you complete yours.